# Show error message by uploading file more than 5 MB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I want to implement service where by uploading file more than 5 MB it will show a message that the file is too big. Until now it works with file format and name length, but somehow it doesn't work with file size.
Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong here:

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateJsionFile(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        //decimal fileSize = 100;
        var supportedTypes = new[] { "txt","doc","docx","pdf", "xls", "xlsx", "png" };
        var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower().Substring(1);
        var maxSize = 5 * 1024 * 1024;
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
        }

        if(!supportedTypes.Contains(fileExt))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, error = "File extention is invalid - upload only WORD/PDF/EXCEL/TXT/PNG files" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        if(file.FileName.Length>50 )
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, error = "File name is too long, max. 50 symbols" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        if (file.ContentLength > maxSize)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, error = "File size is too big, max 5MB" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        using (FileDBEntities db = new FileDBEntities())
        {
            tblFile f = db.tblFiles.Where(p => p.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            f.Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            f.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            f.Data = bytes;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: "...but somehow it doesn't work with file size" - What happens exactly here? What is the behaviour observed?

Comment: it will be uploaded, any size

Comment: If you debug it, what happens at `if (file.ContentLength > maxSize)`? What is the value of `file.ContentLength`?

Comment: {byte[5336642]} ,ContentLength = 0

Comment: @Dimitri - please add additional details to the question as to what is `file.ContentLength` evaluating to at the time of check.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HttpPostedFileBase ContentLength = 0 after reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59967232/httppostedfilebase-contentlength-0-after-reading)

Comment: @Dimitri - then you are basically seeing a byte array in this case, with the content?

Comment: looks like that, but i still dont understand why it doesn't work

Comment: @Dimitri You're accessing the `ContentLength` after reading the steam. Try moving the `BinaryReader` part after the `ContentLength` if block